# Include first child html in custom directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularjs directive for which I load a template:

```
<div class="step" id="stepId" >
</div>
```

Here's the directive declaration:

```
angular.module('PortfolioApp')
  .directive('slideStep', function () {
return {
    templateUrl: appUrl + '/templates/slideStep.html',
    restrict: 'E',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        //element.text('this is the slideStep directive');
          console.log("element text" +element.text());
      },
    replace:true
};
});
```

What I am trying to achieve, is that the html that I include when I use the directive gets included inside the replaced html. So that for example:

```
<slide-step>
    <img src="images/HAC0.jpg"/>
</slide-step>
```

becomes

```
<div class="step" id="stepId" >
   <img src="images/HAC0.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Is there a way to perform this wich allows a simple binding of the first child of element's HTML to the custom element?

Comment: I don't get what your question is about. What do you mean by "[...] a simple binding of the first child of element's HTML to the custom element" ?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. I mean "to embed any html which is included in the html file where the directive is used". So if my directive has some html element inside, such as 
<mydirective>
<span>some text</span>
</mydirective>
the replaced html becomes:
<div class="foo"><!--this is the template html-->
<span>some text</span><!--this is the child of the directive html-->
</div><!--this is the template html-->

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use transclusion:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

```
angular.module('PortfolioApp')
  .directive('slideStep', function () {
return {
    templateUrl: appUrl + '/templates/slideStep.html',
    restrict: 'E',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        //element.text('this is the slideStep directive');
          console.log("element text" +element.text());
      },
    transclude:true,
};
});
```

and in your directive template:

```
<div class="step" id="stepId" ng-transclude>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for, though I noticed that despite the html being correct, the other framework which is using the html generated by angular doesn't work (in this case impress.js) probably because the latter searches for elements when angular still hasn't compiled all directive elements.